# JavaScript window.navigator retornando dados errados?

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando JavaScript, e me deparei com algo estranho, coloquei este comando no console do Chrome `alert(navigator.appCodeName);`, que retorna o nome do navegador, mas sempre retorna, `"Mozilla"`, ao invés de `"Chrome"`, eu gostaria de saber o motivo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa propriedade está deprecada e o seu resultado é de facto sempre o mesmo, em qualquer browser. É mantida nalguns browsers por questões de compatibilidade.

Podes [ler mais sobre isso na MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appCodeName)

> The **NavigatorID.appCodeName** always returns 'Mozilla', on any browser. This property is kept only for compatibility purposes.

Traduzindo livremente é mais ou menos o que escreví aqui.

De onde vem este valor de *Mozilla*?

Há muitos anos atrás não havia tantos browsers como há hoje. O Netscape foi um dos primeiros a ser grande e apareceu na continuação do [Mosaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(web_browser)), e mais tarde surgiu o *Mozilla* (Mosaic + Godzilla). Nesses tempos a primeira maneira de distinguir browsers diferentes foi juntando propriedades (como hoje ainda o `.userAgent`) e esta é uma delas. O que é curioso é que a Microsoft adoptou a mesma propriedade ([segundo este](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) e [este](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) artigos) fazendo-se passar por um browser que na verdade não era. Com isso queria dizer que era compatível com o Netscape, mas invalidou a utilidade de propriedades como essa e daí ela foi deprecada pois é inútil.

Comment: Seria legal complementar a resposta com a leitura [disto](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/).

Comment: @jbueno juntei mais info, obrigado. Ainda vou reler mais logo e juntar mais se estiver em falta.

Comment: Muito interessante, eu não sabia estas coisas, obrigado!